# rdesktop, credSSP and kerberos

Tags: networking, kerberos, rdesktop

I have installed the program rdesktop with the command

```
sudo apt-get install rdesktop
```

I use rdesktop with the command

```
rdesktop -a 32 192.168.0.38
```

with the error message

> Disconnected due to network error, retrying to reconnect for 70
>   minutes. ERROR: CredSSP: Initialize failed, do you have correct
>   kerberos tgt initialized ?

How do I fix the error?

Thanks by advance,

Note: Sorry for my english, i'm french

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved this by using [xfreerdp](https://packages.debian.org/sid/x11/freerdp-x11) instead. I actually tried configuring the Kerberos authentification, but gave up after an hour.

So an example of an xfreerdp command would be:

```
xfreerdp /u:'DOMAIN\john' /p:'doe' host:port
```

Hope that helps even though it's a bit late :-)

Comment: Had the sameproblem: KDE's `krdc` also does not have that issue. But using it of course means a lot of KDE libraries to be installed first....

Comment: Shouldn't it be /v:host:port ?

Comment: Link is broken, very strange

Answer (score 1):

another way is to acquire a ticket from the kerberos server in case you are in a domain.
NLA is an extra security layer which requires the client to authenticate against the Domain before logging on.
After krb5.conf is adequately configured for the domain (google it), you can do the following:

```
kinit <user>
rdesktop -u <user> -d <domain>
```

You only need to execute `kinit` once until the ticket has expired

Comment: Not sure if following, most of the answers suggest this, but how is possible for xfreerdp to do the connection without touching krgb5.conf?